# How to align a HTML element vertically middle?

Tags: html, vertical-alignment

HTML:

```
<th class="someCSS">Text</th>
```

CSS:

```
.someCSS {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

This code is not working. It doesn't align the element vertically middle. How do I do that?

Comment: Try using `text-align: center;`.

Comment: what are you looking for put it in the center of the horizontal line?  or in the middle of the screen or in the center of the vertical?

Comment: It doesn't help. text-align:center; horizontally aligns the element in the center, not vertically middle.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/z7fLq6xw/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you have to work with flexbox I think
because your text can be one word or 500 and it will always stay in the middle of the page

you put a div around your text and then you do what I post

```css
body{
 margin:0px;
 }

.test{
display:flex;

/*justify-content:center;*//*to put in the center of the screen*/

align-items:center;
width:100%;
height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
<th class="someCSS">Text</th>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css `calc()` function to work out the centre point of the containing element and then subtract half the height of the element you wish to center.

```
.container {
  height: 100vh;
}
.element-to-align{
  position: relative;
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  height:100px;
  width: 100px;
}



<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="element-to-align"></div>
 </div> 
</body>
```

Full code below:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html lang="en">  
 <head>  
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <style>
 .container {
   height: 100vh;
 }
 .element-to-align{
   position: relative;
   top: calc(50% - 50px);
   height:100px;
   width: 100px;
   border: red dotted 1px;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
   <div class="element-to-align"></div>
 </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've edited my post to show you it does work. You have to make sure there is a space between the `-` sign and the units in the `calc()` function.

Comment: Let me ask the question in another way. Here is what I want to achieve in the UI: text in the cells of the table to be vertically center inside the cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
        #txt{
            vertical-align: middle;
            height: 190px;
        }
</style>


    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th id="txt">Some Text</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: The `valign` attribute on the `tr` element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.

Comment: Try giving some height to your cell